# Smooth Camera Rotation into Players Facing Direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried posting this in the unity forums but getting answers there is a very rare occurence.

I am trying to write a camera script that follows my character in whatever directions he is facing. Which can only be north, south, west, east (per movement input left or right 90 degree turns each).

So I got this script from a video from Brackeys. I tried implementing the rotation myself but it does not rotate at all, but at least the player is getting followed already. I hope you understand what Im trying to achieve here.

````
{
    public Transform target;

    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;

    public Vector3 offset;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

        transform.LookAt(target);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, target.transform.rotation, smoothSpeed);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transform.LookAt(target)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html);

Also, there is useful:
 [`Quaternion.LookRotation()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)
or you can deal with vectors, instead of quaternions:

```
transform.forward = target.position - transform.position;
```

Comment: But I already got  transform.LookAt(target); in there and it does not rotate accordingly. What do I need to change?

Comment: After doing transform.LookAt(target), which is actually rotates transform, you change rotation again, setting the rotation:     transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, target.transform.rotation, smoothSpeed); Just remove this line.

Comment: Or, if you want to rotate around pivot, there is transform.RotateAround  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html